# Hide a Store View from the store view picker, but keep it active for requests using ?__store=myhiddenstore

Tags: layout, store-view

I'm trying to hide a store view from the store view picker, but keeping it active for requests like mymagento.com?__store=myhiddenstore

Is there a simple way to achieve this? If not, what are good, clean alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

In the layout folder of your theme, create or update local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <remove name="store_language" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This removes the block from the template, but the functionality is retained.